# При перезагрузке страницы сворачивается аккордеон

Tags: jquery

Есть одноуровневый аккордеон, для менюшки на jquery. Проблема состоит в том, что при переходе по ссылке в открышемся подменю категории после обновления страницы активная категория, с которой был совершен переход по ссылке, закрывается, а мне нужно, чтоб она оставалась открытой. Помогите разобратся, плз! Аккордеон организован с помощью списков.

```
$(function () {
$('ul li:has("ul")').append('<span></span>');
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    checkElement.stop().animate({'height':'toggle'}, 500);  
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Пример:

```
Tелефоны
  Nokiya
  Samsung
Ноутбуки
Фонарики
```

В примере открыта категория Телефоны, в подменю названия телефонов (Nokiya, Samsung). Когда я выбираю модель телефона, после перезагрузки и вывода данных выбраной модели категория Телефоны закрывается, а мне нужно, чтоб она оставалась открытой до выбора другой категории. То есть если я нажимаю на Nokiya или Samsung, то всё должно оставатся так же, как в примере после перезагрузки страницы и вывода данныx по выбраной подкатегории, а при переходе на другую категорию она должна закрыватся, и открывается список подменю выбраной категории. Надеюсь, внятно объяснил, если непонятно или нужна дополнительная информация, код или что-то другое, то скажите, дам инфу!

Comment: 1. Оформите код (выделите его и нажмите кнопку отформатированный текст) 2. Не используйте слово "што", ну пожалуйста. 3. После этого даже я Вам помогу.

Comment: @jobananas, При генерировании меню, добавляйте класс к текущей активной ветке. По этому классу и сможете раскрывать необходимые элементы.

Comment: @jobananas, вам нужно в cookie/localStorage писать активную категорию. При изменении списка обновлять запись. При загрузке страницы устанавливать открытую категорию глядя на значение из localstorage.

Comment: а можно наглядный пример, как это может выглядить?

Comment: Примерно понял, как решить мою проблему, когда я нажимаю на подкатегорию после перезагрузки страницы нужно без клика по категории имитировать клик без перехода по ссылке и перезагрузки страницы, тогда активная категория выдаст мне подменю. Как это можно сделать?

Comment:     <a href="<?=$this->items[$i]["link"]?>"><?=$this->items[$i]["title"]?></a>

Comment: @jobananas,

Имитация клика не нужна, это слишком громоздко. Как вариант, для каждого пункта меню просто сравнивайте адрес текущей страницы с адресом данного пункта и при совпадении добавляйте css-класс 'active' для данной вкладки.

    <a class=<?php if($this->items[$i]["link"] == $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) echo "active"; ?> ... ></a>

Если вкладка имеет класс 'active', то она должна остаться открытой (это реализуйте через css).

Да, получится, что нужно прописать такой if для каждого пункта меню. Да, можно значительно упростить и оптимизировать. Достаточно немного подумать.

Answer (score 1):

Всё разобрался всё зделал на всех страницах работает как часики использовал без кукисов и без активов только по гет параметру вынес в родительский клас и заработало всё, всем спасибо и до новых встречь!)
[image: вот как получилось]

Comment: И вот на другой странице
![shop](http://i004.radikal.ru/1501/89/46cc7750003a.png)

Comment: Вопрос можно щитать закрытым!

Comment: что ж вы кодом-то не поделитесь?

Comment: действительно, кодом надо делиться. чтобы такие как вы тоже могли найти ответ на свой вопрос не задавая его ещё раз)).